# Right Click event error

Tags: excel, events, right-click, vba

The right click event I have created displays an error message "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name".

My goal is to right click on a cell and have the count of a column from another sheet input into the target cell.

What is my error that I am missing?

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Set wb = Workbooks("Calc.xlsm")

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = True

Target.Address = Application.count(wb.Sheets("Carrier").Range("O:O"))


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. Your event handler's prototype does not equal what Excel wants it to be. change it into:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
```

You cannot change the signature of event handlers.